# Problems scraping webpage

Tags: powershell, website

I am having problems accessing an invoked webpage HtmlWebResponseObject object.  It was obtained by:

```
PS>$webpage = Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://www.grittv.com/tv-schedule/"
```

After trying to parse/inquire it with:

```
PS>$webpage.AllElements
```

it just sits there with a blinking cursor until I cancel it (30 minutes+ at one time)

Here are some investigations:

```
PS>$webpage | get-member


   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject

Name              MemberType Definition
----              ---------- ----------
Dispose           Method     void Dispose(), void IDisposable.Dispose()
Equals            Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode       Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType           Method     type GetType()
ToString          Method     string ToString()
AllElements       Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollectio...
BaseResponse      Property   System.Net.WebResponse BaseResponse {get;set;}
Content           Property   string Content {get;}
Forms             Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormObjectCollection Form...
Headers           Property   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,string] He...
Images            Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollectio...
InputFields       Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollectio...
Links             Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollectio...
ParsedHtml        Property   mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 ParsedHtml {get;}
RawContent        Property   string RawContent {get;set;}
RawContentLength  Property   long RawContentLength {get;}
RawContentStream  Property   System.IO.MemoryStream RawContentStream {get;}
Scripts           Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollectio...
StatusCode        Property   int StatusCode {get;}
StatusDescription Property   string StatusDescription {get;}
```

```
PS>$webpage.RawContentLength
139792
```

```
PS>$webpage.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    HtmlWebResponseObject                    Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebResponseObject
```

Status code returns `200` and `OK`

What is holding parsing up?
Can you help with invoking this data:?

```
$list = $webpage.allelements | where class -EQ "three-quarters"| select -ExpandProperty innertext
```

Also, it *did* work one time, I believe.  I closed my scripts, came back another day, and it, since, just seemingly hangs.

Invoking on a second computer gave the same results.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Invoke-WebRequest uses the old and buggy IE engine,
so weird stuff is only to be expected.

As a first remark, you are using Invoke-WebRequest, which by default renders
the HTML DOM and confuses completely the AllElements member.
On pages with JavaScript this might make other things happen,
such as IE windows opening or hidden prompts waiting endlessly for
your response.

You need to add to the Invoke-WebRequest the parameter of
`-UseBasicParsing`, like this :

```
$webpage = Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://www.grittv.com/tv-schedule/" -UseBasicParsing
```

The downside when using `-UseBasicParsing` is that you don't have
`.ParsedHtml` and its DOM functions to work with.

The resulting `$webpage` cannot be used with `AllElements`.
You need to directly access its properties.

To list all properties and their values :

```
$webpage | Format-List
```

For example to see all links :

```
$webpage  | select -ExpandProperty Links
```

Comment: Can I get class information from that? I had been using $webpage.allelements | where class -EQ "three-quarters" | select -ExpandProperty innertext